# Is fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt dangerous

Tags: facebook, security

I am using Facebook PHP API and I need to have the file fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt on my server. Is it dangerous if this file is visible from the web and what can someone do with it if he finds it (supopsing he does not have the API secret)?

I can't edit the .htaccess file, so my only option is to hide the facebook library somewhere in the directory tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file is the same for everyone, and does not contain anything about you or your app. There is no danger in someone reading it off your server. It contains intermediate FB certificates so that your code can establish an SSL connection to theirs.